# how to show result of two and more citites of india in google map places api using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

Here is my code

```
<script>
    var placeSearch, autocomplete;
    var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
    };

    function initAutocomplete() {

        var cityBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(28.027138, 73.302155), //bikaner city
            new google.maps.LatLng(26.922070, 75.778885)  //jaipur city
        );

        var options = {
            bounds: cityBounds,
            types: ['geocode'],
            componentRestrictions: {
                country: 'in'
            }
        };
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            options);

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
    }

    function fillInAddress() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
            document.getElementById(component).value = '';
            document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
            }
        }
    }


    function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var geolocation = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
                var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    center: geolocation,
                    radius: position.coords.accuracy
                });
                autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
                autocomplete.setOptions({
                    strictBounds: true
                });
            });
        }
    }

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to show only two cities result of india into the search box to the user but it doesn't work and i am tried so much examples and solution but i didn't found any solution for that it show other cities result also which is i don't want to show. I search it everywhere on google but no solution found then come here please tell me and guide me what i do for that.

> search box code is here

```
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
         onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
```

If any want some more information then please inform me but please help me because it is very important for me

Comment: @JaromandaX i am updating my question with putting search box code

Comment: @JaromandaX please see the question i updated it recently